# Get only the non-inherited fields for a Django mixin

Tags: python, django, mixins

I would like to get all the non-inherited fields defined in a model.  That is, I want the fields defined only in the "submodel", not the base ('abstract') model.  (Ultimate purpose: create a ModelForm that *only* includes the fields defined in the "submodel" - dynamically, without having to write out the specific fields).

Typically calling `vars(Subclass).keys()` will give you only the attributes of Subclass while `dir(Subclass)` will give you the attributes of both SubClass and its inherited class.  I'm trying to use the same paradigm to get only the fields defined in SubModel:

```
class Submodel(models.AbstractModel):
    field1=...
    field2=...

class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    fields...
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
```

But when I call `vars(Submodel).keys()` I get the following (pprinted):

```
[u'__module__',
 '_meta',
 'MultipleObjectsReturned',
 'get_next_by_submission_datetime',
 'get_next_by_some_date_and_time',
 '_base_manager',
 'objects',
 '_default_manager',
 'get_previous_by_submission_datetime',
 'the_foreignkey_field_in_abstractmodel',
 'get_previous_by_some_date_and_time',
 'DoesNotExist',
 '__doc__',
 '__unicode__']
```

I'm not sure why this is returning stuff that is not defined in the Submodel (that seems inconsistent with the usual behavior of vars() ).  And now that I think some more about it, as soon as I define methods on the Submodel, it will return those, which I don't want for constructing a ModelForm.

I have also tried `Submodel._meta.fields` and `Submodel._meta.many_to_many` but those return all of the fields of both AbstractModel and Submodel.

So the main question is: is there a good way to get only the fields defined in the submodel?

And the minor question is:  why is vars() doing that?

EDIT:

In the form definition, what I want to do is:

```
class ExampleinheritForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Submodel
        fields = some_function_to_return_only_Submodel_fields()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's what I ended up doing - works great for me so far.

```
@classmethod
def  get_userdefined_formfields(cls): 
    """Takes all the model fields on a concrete model, 
    and subtracts out the ones in the parent (abstract) model."""
    allfields = cls._meta.fields + cls._meta.many_to_many
    #this assumes we only inherit from one abstract model
    #could be modified if that were not the case
    parentfields = AbstractModel._meta.fields + AbstractModel._meta.many_to_many
    #filter out parent fields
    childfields = [f for f in allfields if f not in parentfields]
    #filter out auto fields and fields without help text, return names
    return childfields
```